# Getting error while invoking flutter_zoom_sdk even though Zoom SDK for Android Is Downloaded

Tags: flutter, android-studio, zooming, zoom-sdk, flutterflow

I'm getting this error in Android Studio, even though I have Zoom SDK for Android downloaded.

May I know the reason why I'm getting this error?

```
PS D:\apps\besupermind\besupermind> flutter pub run flutter_zoom_sdk:unzip_zoom_sdk

Download https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5vfh2m543t15k8/MobileRTC?dl=1 to 
PS D:\apps\besupermind\besupermind> flutter pub run flutter_zoom_sdk:unzip_zoom_sdk
Download https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5vfh2m543t15k8/MobileRTC?dl=1 to C:/Users/Harika%20Perni/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/ios/MobileRTC.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MobileRTC.framework/MobileRTC
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'C:/Users/Harika%20Perni' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)
#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:42:9)
#1      _Directory.create.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:114:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      downloadFile (file:///C:/Users/Harika%20Perni/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/bin/unzip_zoom_sdk.dart:86:26)    
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      checkAndDownloadSDK (file:///C:/Users/Harika%20Perni/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/bin/unzip_zoom_sdk.dart:51:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      main (file:///C:/Users/Harika%20Perni/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/bin/unzip_zoom_sdk.dart:40:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
pub finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.